# Check whether text contains non-ASCII characters in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, character-encoding

I have a file, I want to determine if it contains only English ASCII characters.

I thought this is a very  common question, but when I googled it, there is no direct answer or related.

According to some other questions, this is what I got so far, but this doesn't work. No matter ASCII or Non-ASCII chars, it will always determine as non-ascii.

```
if (LC_ALL=C; [[ $TEXT = *[[:ascii:]]* ]]) then
  echo "Contain Non-ASCII"
fi
```

BTW, This is a shell script.

Answer (score 10):

Your code tests whether the value of the variable `TEXT` contains at least one ASCII character. If you want to test whether `$TEXT` contains non-ASCII characters, you need to invert the set. By the way, `[:ascii:]` is locale-independent, so you don't need to set `LC_CTYPE`.

```
if [[ $TEXT = *[![:ascii:]]* ]]; then
  echo "Contain Non-ASCII"
fi
```

Note that `[:ascii:]` is a bash (and zsh) feature. If you want your script to work in ksh or plain sh, you will need to make use of the locale. Here's a portable method:

```
LC_CTYPE=C
case $TEXT in
  *[![:cntrl:][:print:]]*) echo "Contain Non-ASCII";;
esac
```

If you want to check the file contents, use [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

```
if LC_ALL=C grep -q '[^[:cntrl:][:print:]]' somefile; then
  echo "Contain Non-ASCII"
fi
```

Comment: Fine! How to tell where it is?

Comment: yeah, how can i print the non-ascii char that was found ?

Comment: @DavidGidony Remove the `-q` option from the grep call so that it prints the offending lines, maybe add `-n` to print the line number.

Comment: The example with grep doesn't work for me. It always says `Contains Non-ASCII`. Where as the following command shows me that it has Non-ASCII characters: `grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" somefile` or  `LANG=c sed 's,[\x00-\x7F],,g' somefile > somefile_without_ascii`  creates a new non-zero byte file.


Also this (from yourself about 5 years prior to this answer) https://stackoverflow.com/a/3208902/319542 works! :)

Comment: @PraveenLobo I fixed a mistake in the grep command.

Answer (score 6):

The `file` command can tell you the type of a file (ASCII, unicode, binary, etc.).

```
$ file my_file.txt
my_file.txt: ASCII text
```

So you can just check to see that the output contains the word "ASCII" and this should work:

```
if [[ file my_file.txt | grep -i ascii ]] ...
```

Comment: FYI - Caution grepping for "ASCII" alone.  Other things than plain ascii may come from "file".  For instance:
    Non-ISO extended-ASCII text

Answer (score -1):

```
TEXT=SOMETEXTHERE

RESULT=$(echo $TEXT | LC_COLLATE=C grep -r '[^ -~]')
if [ -z "$RESULT" ]; then
    echo "ALL ASCII"
else
    echo "Contain Non-ASCII"
fi
```